# Python PyQt widget positioning in grid

Tags: python, qt, grid, pyqt

Here is my code:

```
#class...
def setupLayout(self):
    self.resize(1000, 600)
    label1 = QtGui.QLabel(u'<font color=green><b><i>Полученные сообщения:</i></b></font>')
    label2 = QtGui.QLabel(u'<font color=green><b><i>Описание сообщений:</i></b></font>')

    self.mainList = QtGui.QListWidget()
    self.descList = QtGui.QListWidget()
   
    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    grid.setSpacing(1)
    
    grid.addWidget(label1, 1, 1)
    grid.addWidget(label2, 1, 2)
  
    grid.addWidget(self.mainList, 2, 1, 5, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.descList, 2, 2, 5, 1)
#other definitions....
```

I want to reduce distance between my labels and panel with the title of the window:
[image: grid layout problem]

So if I use this code, the distance is good, but listBoxes holds only one row:

```
grid.addWidget(self.mainList, 2, 1, 1, 1)
grid.addWidget(self.descList, 2, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

How can I add a small distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `QGridLayout` for homogeneous contents. For your purpose a combination of `QHBoxLayout` and `QVBoxLayout` would work better.

```
left = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
# This makes the label take as little space as possible
# since QLabel's sizeHint is Minimum.
left.addWidget(label1, 0)
left.addWidget(self.mainList, 1)

right = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
right.addWidget(label2, 0)
right.addWidget(self.descList, 1)

main = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
main.addLayout(left, 1)    # Both sides take the same amount of space.
main.addLayout(right, 1)
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Ok, I will try your decision for three columns.

Comment: How I can add a new line (long line under two listBoxes)? And how I can add several lineEdits one under another to the right of the descList? This positioning is so complicated :(

Comment: Yeah Qt layout can be pretty hard to understand in the beginning. It's pretty powerful and thus complicated. For a long line you might want to wrap the whole thing above in another vbox, and add the line under the `main` hbox above. (You might have trouble *drawing* the line, though—Qt does not have a widget for that.) For the line edits you put them all in a vbox, and then add the vbox after (i.e. to the right) of the `main` hbox.